# SQL INDENTITY DOESN'T RECEIVE PARAMETERS

Tags: sql, identity

I'm trying to set IDENTITY seed parameter while creating table, getting it from a var. Something like this

```
DECLARE @MaxID INTEGER
SET @MaxID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.ProductQuotes ORDER BY ID DESC) + 1;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Z](
 [ID] int PRIMARY KEY not null IDENTITY(@MaxID,1),
 [Number] int NULL,
 [Name] nvarchar(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Error is "incorrect syntax near '@MaxID' (in this row [ID] int PRIMARY KEY not null IDENTITY(@MaxID,1) )

But I'm not sure it's about syntax at all. Can somebody explain me where am I wrong here? :)

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this. What is the reason for doing this? Also what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: this table is used as temp for a complex import process, so it needs to have correct identity seed to be innerjoined with the main table to finish the import. Could you explain a bit more about dynamic sql ?

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 you can use a SEQUENCE to ensure contiguous numbers across both tables http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: @gbn - It ensures order not contiguity (as does `IDENTITY`)

Comment: @MartinSmith: true, but it allows IDs to be preallocated so there is no conflict on ProductQuotes (as your answer noted) and avoids dynamic SQL

Comment: @MartinSmith: and I didn't really mean contiguous. I meant "shared unique". http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44289/630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be parameterised.

You would need to use dynamic SQL as below.

```
DECLARE @MaxID INTEGER

SELECT @MaxID = 1 + ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM dbo.ProductQuotes

DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Z](
 [ID] int PRIMARY KEY not null IDENTITY(' + CAST(@MaxID AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ',1),
 [Number] int NULL,
 [Name] nvarchar(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
'

EXEC (@Script);
```

I assume you will take precautions to ensure that `ProductQuotes` cannot be subject to any inserts during the import process.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
DECLARE @MaxID INTEGER
DECLARE @SQL varChar(4000)
SET @MaxID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.ProductQuotes ORDER BY ID DESC) + 1;

Set @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Z]([ID] int PRIMARY KEY not null IDENTITY(' +
Convert(VarChar(8),@MaxID) + 
',1), [Number] int NULL, [Name] nvarchar(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
Exec(@sql)
```

Build the sql statement using the teh value of @MaxID then execute it.